# CSS Width Problem form PC to PC

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have make this layout.
[template](http://nausal.com/testcode/moringa/index.html)

Only problem is the width problem.. Its vary form monitor to monitor, depend on the width of the monitor. The main menu and header area has empty area form its left and right side. Same you can see in case of footer.. i have fixed width of 1007px according to my monitor width. but on laptop with wide screen it has problem with header and footer div.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get what the problem is or what you expect as an anwer, the broken english also doesn't help. Can you give more information?

Comment: You should check this link by zoom in and zoom out your browser.. You will see the difference in header area.

Answer (score 0):

Give your wrapper a background color:

```
div#page-wrap {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1007px;
}
```

Comment: Problem is not with the main content area.. Problem is with header area.. its Blank form left and right side.. How can i stretch header area just like main content form one pc to another pc

Comment: You want the header to go right across the whole screen? Remove it out  the wrapper that was the 1007 width set.